# How to convert PostgreSQL row (record) to JSON and don't lose numeric type precision settings

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have an arbitrary set of (temp) tables and queries with some numeric columns.
For example:

```
 id | a_text | a_numeric3(4,3) | a_numeric2(5,2) | ... more columns
----+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------
 1  | str 1  |           3.950 |            1.23 | ...
 2  | str 2  |           3.377 |           65.20 | ...
 3  | ...
```

I need to convert this data ta JSON. Now I do it this way:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_agg(row_to_json(temp_table12)) 
   INTO jsonb_rows 
FROM temp_table12;
```

and get result like this:

```
[{"id": 1, "a_text": "str 1", "a_numeric2": 1.23, "a_numeric3": 3.950, ...},
 {"id": 2, "a_text": "str 2", "a_numeric2": 65.20, "a_numeric3": 3.377, ...}, ...]
```

but this will lead to the following problem after parsing: losing information about numeric type precision settings: **3.950** & **65.20** parsed exactly like **3.95** & **65.2**.

To work around the problem I need to cast numeric to text:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_agg(row_to_json(tt)) 
   INTO jsonb_rows 
FROM (SELECT *, a_numeric3::text, a_numeric2::text FROM temp_table12) AS tt;
```

The good result:

```
[{"id": 1, "a_text": "str 1", "a_numeric2": "1.23", "a_numeric3": "3.950", ...},
 {"id": 2, "a_text": "str 2", "a_numeric2": "65.20", "a_numeric3": "3.377", ...}, ...]
```

**Question**: Is there any way I can avoid manual type casting with column enumeration?

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_agg(row_to_json__numeric_as_text(temp_table12)) 
  INTO jsonb_rows 
FROM temp_table12;
```

or

```sql
SELECT jsonb_agg(row_to_json(row_cast_numeric_to_text(temp_table12))) 
  INTO jsonb_rows 
FROM temp_table12;
```

If there are no such ready-made library solutions, how can I write functions like *row_to_json__numeric_as_text* or *row_cast_numeric_to_text* in Pl/PgSQL? (For the general case when I do not know the names of columns in *record*.)

Comment: You could store the values as strings, if you want to maintain the trailing zeros.

Comment: Yes I can do so, but it is inconvenient because then I immediately lose the ability to perform calculations with these values. For example, calculate the aggregate sum.